# What does `vec type 'AnonymousBundle(IO io in <module>)' must be a Chisel type, not hardware` mean?

Tags: module, hdl, chisel

The following line of code `val mod_subexp_array = Vec(9, Module(new SubTaylor(fepar)).io)` produces the following error:

```
chisel3.package$ExpectedChiselTypeException: vec type 'AnonymousBundle(IO io in SubTaylor)' must be a Chisel type, not hardware
```

The module `SubTaylor` is a module I've written, and I interface with it via an IO port. My objective is to create 9 instances of these SubTaylor modules and chain them together using their IOs. To resolve the problem above, I thought perhaps the SubTaylor module needed to be wrapped within a Wire:

`val mod_subexp_array = Vec(9, Wire(Module(new SubTaylor(fepar))).io)`

However, the errors message changed to `wire type 'AnonymousBundle(IO io in SubTaylor)' must be a Chisel type, not hardware`. As I currently understand, there are two different Wire datatypes. One wire datatype is a Chisel type, and the other is a hardware type. Is my understanding correct? And how am I supposed to define Vector as a Chisel type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to write is the following:

```scala
val mod_subexp_array = VecInit(Seq.fill(9, Module(new SubTaylor(fepar))).io))
```

What that error message means is that you provided a hardware *value* instead of a *type* when a type was expected. I'll explain by analogy with C:

```c
// This is how you make an Array of 10 ints
int my_array[10];
// This is analogous to Vec(9, Wire(Module(new SubTaylor(fepar))).io)
3 my_array[10]; /*
^ An int value instead of a type
*/
```

I know this distinction is a little more obvious in C than in Chisel (because Chisel is a generator metaprogramming framework), but it's effectively the same thing.
`Vec(<n>, <type>)` is how you create a Vec *type*. `VecInit(<values>)` is how you create a Vec *value*.

You may wonder why we are using `Seq.fill`? `Seq` is a Scala type and we are using a factory method to stamp out 9 instances of your Module. `VecInit` accepts a `Seq` of whatever hardware type you're creating so it will take those 9 instances and turn it into a hardware value.

Comment: This answer right here needs to be part of the Chisel docs/tutorial. I spent days going in circles until I found this and everything clicked when I read it.